# Contagem progressiva usando for

Tags: javascript, for

Se eu fizer esse for:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  document.write(i);
}
```

O resultado vai ser: 123456789

Como faço pra ao invés de ser assim: 123456789, ele criar uma contagem com um numeral só?

Tipo uma contagem progressiva.

Comment: O que é "uma contagem com um numeral só"?

Comment: Isso que fiquei com dificultade explicar. Sabe quando a gente ta digitando aqui e mostra quantos caracteres estão faltando? "N caracteres restantes" no casso, esse N, seria "Um numeral só".

Comment: Você quer que ele imprima: 9999999999 - ou você quer que ele execute o loop 10 vezes, mas na última vez ele escreva: 9? Ou nenhum dos dois?

Comment: Só piorou, agora nem tenho ideia do que está falando, esse comentário não parece indicar nada relacionado ao que está na pergunta.

Comment: veja se é isso que vc quer... http://jsfiddle.net/hqh6Lne9/

Comment: Olha minha edição. So aparece um número, certo? Só vai diminuindo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode passar argumentos para a função:

```js
var span = document.querySelector('span');

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(a) {    
    span.innerHTML = a;    
  }, i * 1000, i);
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

O método [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) recebe como argumentos uma função para ser executada depois que o tempo expira, onde nesse caso é `function(a)`.

O tempo, em Milissegundos, que o método irá esperar antes de executar a função, que nesse caso é `i * 1000` - `i * 1000` porque a cada iteração o *timer* var aguardar um tempo diferente (um segundo a mais a cada chamada). `1000` Milissegundos é igual a 1 segundo, nesse caso, o timer irá exibir o contador com 1 segundo de intervalo.

E por último, o método aceita parâmetros, quantos precisar, que poderá ser usada na função interna - nesse caso o parâmetro `a` da função terá o valor do último parâmetro em `, i * 1000, i);`

Comment: Sempre presente os downvotes anônimos :p

Comment: Também não sei o motivo do downvote pra você, foi a melhor resposta ao meu ver. No caso, teve downvote pra todos, não entendi.

Comment: Pode me explicar esse final, Lucas? i * 1000, i

Comment: Claro @LucasCarvalho, editei a resposta, se não ficou muito claro pergunte aqui

Comment: Não, o i * 1000 eu entendi, só não entendi o ,i (virgula i) kk

Comment: Isso, serão os parâmetros que poderão ser usados na função.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado! :)

Answer (score 0):

Lucas, 
se o programa for executado no console ele segue um padrão de execução e imprime tudo que for mandando, não possibilitando um clear, mas há uma gambiarra. A "solução" é usar o `console.clear()`, só que o problema reside na diferença de execução de browser para browser, como aponta [essa página](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/clear) do MDN.

Caso seja para uma textArea ou div:

```
var i = 0;
theLabel = document.getElementById("minhaDiv");
var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
    if (i == 100) clearInterval(interval);
    theLabel.innerHTML = i; 
    i++;
}, 
1000);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
        var i = 10;
theLabel = document.getElementById("counter");
var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
    
    theLabel.innerHTML = i; 
    i--;
}, 
1000);
```

```html
<div id="counter"></div>
```

Comment: Gostaria de entender pq deram -1 na minha resposta se é válida?

Comment: Eu não sei qual foi o motivo do negativo porém sempre deixa uma descrição sucinta de como o código funciona. Respostas com código somente as vezes acabam caindo na fila revisão.

Answer (score -2):

Olá voce tem que colocar seu contador em um div e ir alterando ele com o tempo

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=i
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
</div>
```

Mas eu acredito que um spinner seja uma solução melhor que essa.

```css
.loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" class="loader"></div>
```

Ai você coloca um timeout.
acho que é para mostrar o load da pagina que você quer eu não estou colocando todo o código mas se for isso que você quer vou atras.